# Custom advance filtering on Sharepoint list view [Sharepoint Online] using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a webpart in Sharepoint online, that, works like a advance filtering.

Functionality of the webpart:

1. This app will show advance filtering options
   For example: 
   they can choose: Category[column name], File type [doc, ppt], file name so on

   I know there is default filtering options on sharepoint list. However, my effort is to make this advance filtering webpart appear on top of the list and choose filtering options instead of going to list setting and apply filtering. 
   This will have many options which are not in the default list filtering options.
2. User can save the this filter for later use.

My question is:

Is it programmatically possible to apply filters, with, my own filtering options? [Sharepoint online webpart, hence, using JavaScript]

If so, kindly give me some idea. Since, Sharepoint online development is pretty new. I am running short of useful documentation.

Comment: A link-only answer below [gives this link](https://platinumdogs.me/2014/07/15/dynamically-filtering-sharepoint-list-views-using-javascript/).